# qlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, sql

I am getting this error "qlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" with the following code:

```
$theusername = $_POST['username'];

$query="SELECT firstName,lastName FROM staff WHERE username='$theusername'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

     $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);

     echo '<br>First Name: <input type="text" name="newfirst" id="newfirst" value="'.$row['firstName'].'">';
     echo '<br>Last Name: <input type="text" name="newlast" id="newlast" value="'.$row['lastName'].'">';
```

It works fine without the WHERE username='$theusername' in the sql statement like this:

```
$query="SELECT firstName,lastName FROM staff";
```

Which manages to just get the first entry in the database, although this is not what I want it is confusing why it will work for that but not with the WHERE.

The $theusername is valid and contains a valid 'username' that exists in the table/database.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your query failed, is the connection established?

Comment: Yes it is, as said above it works fine with just: $query="SELECT firstName,lastName FROM staff";

Comment: and is the field name correct in where clause? could it be `userName`? And why not try `print_r(sqlsrv_errors());`

Comment: It is indeed.

Error:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 402 [code] => 402 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. ) )

Comment: Fixed, the data type for the column's where wrong.